# Moving external libraries "inside" your project

Tags: c++, cmake

assuming I currently use

```
target_link_libraries(...)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt, which requires the libraries to be installed on the computer I am compiling on, is there a way to move these external libraries inside my project (e.g. into a libs/ folder)?

Comment: I think you have to be more specific to what that means.

Comment: If you want to copy the `.lib` files or `.dll`s yes one could with a bit of work write cmake functions / macros to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but there is multiple ways.

My most preferred is to actually install those libraries in the `libs/` directory so the structure look like this:

```
- libs/
    -lib1/
       - include
       - lib
    -lib2/
       - include
       - lib
```

It's done by simply installing the library inside the directory of your project:

```
# inside lib1/build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/my/project/libs/lib1
make install
```

Then, in your project you can set the prefix path to the `libs/` directory:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_PATH}/libs/")
# ...
find_package(lib1) # find the library in libs/lib1
```

---

The other ways would be to use `add_subdirectory` and have the source of the project inside `libs`. You'll be able to use the target they define so you can link to them.